# Azure AD B2C Guest User can not log in

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Hi all and thanks for reading.

**Context**:

I have created an Azure Active Directory B2C and added a Sign In policy and created 2 applications in the B2C (one for my api and one for the front-end application). I have also added the API to the front end application its "API access" panel.

Afterwards I created a new guest user by clicking the "New Guest User" button and invited a colleague of mine with his company email.

**Problem**:

He received the mail and accepted everything but now he cannot log in on the front end application that uses the b2c settings nor when he uses the URL I copied from the Sign In policy "run now endpoint".

Did I do something wrong? Am I wrong when I think that a guest user should be able to log in to the AD B2C after accepting the invite, should I do something else?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A guest user cannot be authenticated by a sign-in policy because policies are scoped to users that are created as [local and social account users](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#CreateLocalAccountUser).

(A guest user, however, can administer the Azure AD B2C directory, policies, and other Azure AD B2C settings if they are assigned to the Global Administrator role.)

Comment: Did you find any solution ?